# How to detect if user is speaking with phone in android

Tags: android

I need to know user is speaking with phone or not, i tried to track if ACTION_RECOGNIZE_SPEECH is available or not but it is available when user is speaking with phone, so how can i know that?

Comment: your problem occured when voice recognition not supported device or when device not use. right..?

Comment: no i'm trying to find out if user is talking on the phone or not, (when he making outgoing call), so i'm looking for something that be available when user is not using call, and be unavailable when user is using call

Comment: you looking for check calling status..? like below right..?

Comment: no i'm not, i know user is in OFFHOOK, i'm trying to know if call is answered

Comment: ok then you should call record first and get frequency of voice if change frequency of voice cross some level then you can detect

Comment: do you have any sample?